# password_prompt in ANT

Tags: eclipse, ant

From a previous job, I learned that the adding the following command line  parameter to the ANT configuration in Eclipse displays a password prompt.

-Ddp.password=${password_prompt:DP password}

This prompts you for a password, everytime you run an ANT task and the input is nicely masked with dots.

I could not find any documentation about this feature, though. I would like to use a similar mechanism to prompt for the username.

Can someone please help me on track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string_prompt` to prompt for an unmasked string. So something like

```
-Duserid=${string_prompt:Enter userid}
```

The `Variables` button on the 'Arguments' section of the External Tools Configuration for the Ant script lists all the available variables with a short description of each.